# Postgres - limit number of rows COPY FROM

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

Is there a way to limit the Postgres `COPY FROM` syntax to only the first row? There doesn't seem to be an option listed in the documentation.

I know there's that functionality in SQL Server, see `FIRSTROW` AND `LASTROW` options below:

```
BULK INSERT sometable
FROM 'E:\filefromabove.txt
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
LASTROW = 4,
FIELDTERMINATOR= '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `PROGRAM` option to preprocess the file to read from the standard output.

To load only the first line use

**Unix/Linux/Mac**

```
COPY sometable from PROGRAM 'head -1 filefromabove.txt' ;
```

**Windows**

```
COPY sometable from PROGRAM 'set /p var= <filefromabove.txt && echo %var%' ;
```